# Improved Performance when using Window.partitionBy instead of groupBy

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have one scala-spark dataframe with three columns say Col1, Col2 and Col3. This dataframe has around 54 million rows.

What I want is max of Col3 per Col1,Col2 combination like below

[[image: DataSet]]

```scala
val maxDf = df.groupBy(Col1, Col2).agg(F.max(Col3))
```

[[image: Expected Result]]

But when I am trying to achieve above using `groupBy` somehow it is failing with below error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 8168736160 bytes of memory, got 0
```

Then I tried the same using Window function

```scala
val window  = Window.partitionBy("Col1","Col2")

val maxDf = df.withColumn("maxVal", F.max("Col3").over(window))
```

Somehow above code got executed successfully. I am trying to find out the reason behind this as theoretically both the operation are similar and have same execution plan.

Comment: Could you add the execution plan and the partition number for both cases?

Comment: No . of shuffle partitions in both the cases is 3000.
Execution plan for both is as follow :
1) GroupBy
  a) Hash aggregate to group by columns in one stage. 
  b) data exchange between stages.
  c) Hash aggregate to calculate max.
2) Window
 a) sorting of Col1 and Col2 in one stage.
 b) data exchange between stages.
 c) Hash aggregate to partition data by col1 and col2 then hash aggregate to calculate max in same stage.

Comment: any conclusions here?